# git clone without objects to do git log

Tags: git, download, git-clone, revision-history

How can I clone a git repository without getting the actual files and all their revision deltas?
I only want to be able to do `git log | grep`, no need to access files' contents.

I would like to skip this part of the cloning:

```
Receiving objects:  12% (359112/2981072), 432.66 MiB | 1.67 MiB/s
```

There are some repositories whose logs I want to grep, but without downloading/checking out the whole repository, because they weigh gigabytes. Even a solution where I only get a single branch's logs (e.g. master) interests me, if that helps.

---

Essentially I'm looking for something like `svn log <repo url>` for `git`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Partial clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone) is now available in more recent versions of git:

```sh
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout git@github.com:foo/bar.git
```

Comment: Tested this on https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin.git and indeed, it only downloaded 230MB instead of 1.4G. A note: with a clone like this even `git fetch` won't download much more data. Awesome! (Beware: `git status` will fetch `master` to some extent)