# How to find the remote branch containing the specified commit without getting the full repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, tags, branch

I have a repository with many branches, and I have tagged each commit with a specific tag, so I can find it with `git ls-remote --tags`, but I can't find the corresponding branch with that tag, I don't want to pull all branches every time

I tried to run this command but it didn't work `git branch -r --contains <commit>`
It prompts this `error: malformed object name <commit>`

Comment: Can you show us the `git branch` command and the output in the question?

Comment: What is the value of `<commit>`?  Are you trying to use the tag name there?

Comment: I used the tag and the commit both didn't work, but they do exist in the remote repository

Comment: This may help you, if you wish to [clone the history without the files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36547904/184546).

Comment: @TTT Thank you, it works and successfully solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

What you have in `<commit>` is not valid as a SHA for an actual commit.  This is why you have this error.

You may also be using a SHA that doesn't exist on any of your branches so git is not able to find it and it gives this error in that case.

Comment: well... that makes sense.... but the error message is a little misguiding, right?

Comment: Just checked and your theory holds water.... it's even reinforced by this part of the question: _I don't want to pull all branches every time_. Maybe the OP is not fetching?

Comment: I used `--depth=1` when cloning, I don't want to clone all of them because they are too big

Comment: @wxy if you don't have all the commits, you will get this error when the commit that you are looking for isn't in your clone of the repo

Comment: Sorry, my question is how to find the branch containing the specified commit without getting the full repository

Comment: @wxy you can't. Git needs to have the sha locally in order to find it otherwise how would it know that it exists